# Include NULL in SQL Join when using WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I have the following two tables:

- Table ***TempUser22*** : 57,000 rows:

> ```
> +------+-----------+
> | Id   | Followers |
> +------+-----------+
> |  874 |     55542 |
> | 1081 |    330624 |
> | 1378 |     17919 |
> | 1621 |       920 |
> | 1688 |    255463 |
> | 2953 |       751 |
> | 3382 |    204466 |
> | 3840 |    273489 |
> | 4145 |       376 |
> | ...  |       ... |
> +------+-----------+
> ```

- Table ***temporal_users*** : 10,000,000 rows total, 3200 rows Where Date=2010-12-31:

> ```
> +---------------------+---------+--------------------+
> | Date                | User_Id | has_original_tweet |
> +---------------------+---------+--------------------+
> | 2008-02-22 12:00:00 |  676493 |                  2 |
> | 2008-02-22 12:00:00 |  815263 |                  1 |
> | 2008-02-22 12:00:00 | 6245822 |                  1 |
> | 2008-02-22 12:00:00 | 8854092 |                  1 |
> | 2008-02-23 12:00:00 |  676493 |                  2 |
> | 2008-02-23 12:00:00 |  815263 |                  1 |
> | 2008-02-23 12:00:00 | 6245822 |                  1 |
> | 2008-02-23 12:00:00 | 8854092 |                  1 |
> | 2008-02-24 12:00:00 |  676493 |                  2 |
> |    .............    |   ...   |                 .. |
> +---------------------+---------+--------------------+
> ```

I am running the following join query on these tables:

```
SELECT sum(has_original_tweet), b.Id
  FROM temporal_users AS a
  RIGHT JOIN TempUser22 AS b
  ON a.User_ID = b.Id
  GROUP BY b.Id;
```

Which returns 57,00 rows as expected, with NULL answers on the first field:

> ```
> +-------------------------+------+
> | sum(has_original_tweet) | Id   |
> +-------------------------+------+
> |                    NULL |  874 |
> |                    NULL | 1081 |
> |                     135 | 1378 |
> |                     164 | 1621 |
> |                     652 | 1688 |
> |                     691 | 2953 |
> |                    NULL | 3382 |
> |                    NULL | 3840 |
> |                    NULL | 4145 |
> |                     ... | .... |
> +-------------------------+------+
> ```

However, when adding the WHERE line specifying a date as below:

```
SELECT sum(has_original_tweet), b.Id
  FROM temporal_users AS a
  RIGHT JOIN TempUser22 AS b
  ON a.User_ID = b.Id
  WHERE a.Date BETWEEN '2010-12-31-00:00:00' AND '2010-12-31-23:59:59'
  GROUP BY b.Id;
```

I receive the following answer, of only 3200 rows, and without any NULL in the first field.

> ```
> +-------------------------+---------+
> | sum(has_original_tweet) | Id      |
> +-------------------------+---------+
> |                       1 |  797194 |
> |                       1 |  815263 |
> |                       0 |  820678 |
> |                       1 | 1427511 |
> |                       0 | 4653731 |
> |                       1 | 5933862 |
> |                       2 | 7530552 |
> |                       1 | 7674072 |
> |                       1 | 8149632 |
> |                      .. |   ....  |
> +-------------------------+---------+
> ```

My question is: How to get, for a given date, an answer of size 57,000 rows for each user in *TempUser22* with NULL values when has_original_tweet is not present in temporal_user for the given date?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that the nulls your are getting have dates outside of the range you are specifying?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT b.Id, SUM(a.has_original_tweet) s
FROM TempUser22 b
LEFT JOIN temporal_users a ON b.Id = a.User_Id
  AND a.Date BETWEEN '2010-12-31-00:00:00' AND '2010-12-31-23:59:59'
GROUP BY b.Id;

Id  s
1   null
2   1
3   null
4   3
5   null
6   null
```

For debugging, I used:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TempUser22(Id INT, Followers INT)
  SELECT 1 Id, 10 Followers UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 20 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 30 UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 40 UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 50 UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, 60
;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temporal_users(`Date` DATETIME, User_Id INT, has_original_tweet INT)
  SELECT '2008-02-22 12:00:00' `Date`, 1 User_Id, 1 has_original_tweet UNION ALL

  SELECT '2008-12-31 12:00:00', 2, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2010-12-31 12:00:00', 2, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2012-12-31 12:00:00', 2, 1 UNION ALL

  SELECT '2008-12-31 12:00:00', 4, 9 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2010-12-31 12:00:00', 4, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2010-12-31 12:00:00', 4, 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2012-12-31 12:00:00', 4, 9
;
```

Comment: That's it ! I have to avoid using WHERE, simply use AND instead. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `NULL` values will always be discarded from the `where` clause

You can use a coalesce in your `where` clause.

```
WHERE coalesce(a.Date, 'some-date-in-the-range') BETWEEN '2010-12-31-00:00:00' AND '2010-12-31-23:59:59'
```

With this instead, you force `null` values to be considered as valid.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it did not work, this stateement did not return all of the 57,000  *b.Id* .

Comment: Replacing WHERE by AND did the trick actually, thanks though.

Comment: When you use an outer join (whether left or right) and put a where condition on the second table, you force the join to become an inner join. So a LEFT JOIN b if you put a condition on table 'b' or a RIGHT JOIN table b and you put a condition on table 'a' you want that condition in the ON clause not a WHERE.